# afterpage package and verse environment cause troubleshooting

Tags: debugging, verse, afterpage

I use both `afterpage` package and `verse` environment in my document.

So, when a `verse` environment comes just after an `\afterpage` command rendering, an unwanted linebreak occurs after the first verse.

As example, this a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{AFTER PAGE}

\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{verse}
lorem\\
ipsum\\
dolor\\
sit\\
amet\\
et\\
consectetur
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

This is the rendering of the second page, the one who immediately follow the `\afterpage` command’s output.

[image: Unwanted linebreak rendering]

As you see, between ipsum and dolor an unwanted blank line appears.

How to fix this bug when a `verse` environement follow at the top page an `\afterpage` rendering?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{AFTER PAGE}

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

%\clearpage

\begin{verse}
lorem\\
ipsum\\
dolor\\
sit\\
amet\\
et\\
consectetur
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a version without lipsum package, can't look now but you could raise an issue at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues (with the version not using lipsum)  an immediate workaround is to add `\clearpage` at the point the page break happens.

Comment: It’s done at this URL https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/611

Comment: Thanks, no promises but it won't get forgotten now it's there.

Comment: You can "fix" it by adding a `\pagebreak` before `\begin{verse}`.

Comment: You should see what `\afterpage{AFTER PAGE\hrule}` does!

Comment: @JohnKormylo what `\hrule` is supposed to do? It just add an hrule (as expected) and break page. And at last, the unwanted blank line still. It’s note usefull at all.

Comment: It causes a page break!  It should only draw a line across the page without adding any space at all (flush with the top of whatever comes next).